# Add a content to file and if already present then don't add

Tags: java, file, io

I want to write into a file. But before writing, I want to check whether that content is already present in the file or not. If the content is present then don't add it; if not, then add. How can I do this in Java?

My code is like this:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
    System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine() +":" + orphan);
    if(bufferedReader.readLine().equals(orphan)){
        System.out.println("Matched ==============");
        check = true ;
        break;
    }
}

if(check != true) {
    System.out.println("writting the value ");
    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath, true));
    bufferedWriter.write(orphan);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    bufferedWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: Before writing, just read the file. Check if the content is similar to what you want to add to the file. If not, write to the file.

Comment: I'd start with research then move to trial and error.

Comment: Come again with these requirements .. What type of file?  What format of file? And in which part  of your code you are facing problem ?

Comment: I am reading the file and but it is checking only the last value.

Comment: I have a .lst file which contains the list of all First-Names . so , now next time if i wanted to add new name , then my code should read the file and check whether it contains the name which we are writting , so if it contains then it should not added but if not then added .

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays in the way you try to read the content of your file.

```
while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) { // read line n
    System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine() +":" + orphan); // read line n + 1
    if(bufferedReader.readLine().equals(orphan)){ // read line n + 2
        System.out.println("Matched ==============");
        check = true ;
        break;
    }
}
```

Each time you call bufferedReader.readLine() it reads the next line.
Your code should look something like this (untested!):

```
String input = bufferedReader.readLine(); // read line n
while (input != null) { 
    System.out.println(input +":" + orphan);
    if(input.equals(orphan)){
        System.out.println("Matched ==============");
        check = true ;
        break;
    }
    input = bufferedReader.readLine(); // read line n+1
}
```